# Lambda function to color code certain values in mvc3 view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda

I have the following code within a razor mvc3 view that is duplicated in a couple of grids and tables to color code values:

```
        @{var val= @@item.value * 100);}
        @if(@val < 85) { <div style='color: #C11B17' > @val.ToString("0.0")%</div> }         
        @if(@val >= 85 && osi <=95 ) { <div style='color: #AF7817' > @val.ToString("#.0")%</div> }         
        @if(@val > 95 && osi <=115) { <div style='color: green' > @val.ToString("#.0")%</div> }                  
        @if(@val > 115) { <div style='color: blue' > @val.ToString("#.0")%</div> }
```

How can I re-write to an equivalent lambda function so I can reuse within my view?

Comment: Why do you need a lambda function, why not just a simple helper method?

Comment: @PinnyM: Lambda might not be the correct tool but I would like to keep it local to my .cshtml file.  I don't have to have to add a helper that  is defined in another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this method in a non-rendered block and call it as needed:

```
@{
  Func<Decimal, string> helperMethod = (Decimal val) => 
  {
      var template = "<div style='color: {0}' > {1}%</div>";
      var color = ""
      var format = "#.0";
      if(val < 85) { color = "#C11B17"; format = "0.0"; }         
      else if(val >= 85 && osi <=95 ) { color = "#AF7817"; }         
      else if(val > 95 && osi <=115) { color = "green"; }                  
      else if(val > 115) { color = "blue"; }
      else return "";
      return String.Format(template, color, val.ToString(format));
  };
}
```

Now you can call the method anywhere in that template:

```
@Html.Raw(helperMethod(item.Value*100))
```

Comment: QQ, it's actually giving me the following error: "Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable" highlighting the var helperMethod line

Comment: Try changing 'var helperMethod' to 'Func<Decimal, string> helperMethod' as above